# Is there a way to filter out Retweets from results of search_tweets using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to query Tweets with certain keywords and am able to a get a list of Tweet objects (or Status objects?) (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet).

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove Retweets from all the Tweets since I want to look at original Tweets and replies specifically. If there's an attribute in the Tweet object, that'd solve my problem but didn't figure that out so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) with [`API.search_tweets`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets), you can use the `-filter:retweets` [operator](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators) in your query.

Also, if you're using `API.search_tweets`, you're using Twitter API v1.1, and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet is the corresponding documentation for the Tweet object. You can distinguish Retweets by the existence of a `retweeted_status` attribute.

Comment: Thanks you so much! The operator works very well. Can I ask a question about the object? When I'm using `retweeted_status`, it says `AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweeted_status'`. I'm confused why Twitter doc doesn't contain an object called Status?

Comment: Tweepy's `Status` object represents Twitter API v1.1's Tweet object. You'll have to check for the existence of the attribute, e.g. with [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).

Comment: just marked. Sorry, first time using it.